# Deleting "via us-imm-node4c.000webhost.io" in php e-mails

Tags: php, email, gmail

I have tested a php script to send e-mails. When the message arrives, it says: **genera01.000webhost.com via us-imm-node4c.000webhost.io**

I have looked for information about how to delete the  **via us-imm-node4c.000webhost.io** part, but I have found nothing

The php code is this:

```
 <?php
$to      = 'someemail@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = '<html>
<body>
  <p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a></p>
</body>
</html>';
$headers = 'From: genera01.000webhost.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't get rid of it. You can try to write something without an @, so it says something like "example" + "@us-imm-node4c.000webhost.io".

Example:

```
<?php
$to      = 'someemail@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = '<html>
<body>
  <p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a></p>
</body>
</html>';
$headers = 'From: example' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```